# Max-width and max-height for images in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Yet again Internet Explorer is costing me time and money.

I'm making a responsive site and I'm needing my images to be no more than 100% width of their containing elements, but also no more than a certain percentage height in case they fall off the page.

Some CSS:

```
#content{

    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:320px;
    max-width:800px;
    width:80%;
    background-color:green;

}

#featured{

    position:relative;
    width:100%;

}

#featured-images{

    text-align:center;

}

#featured-images img{

    max-height:80%;
    height:auto !important; /* IE fix */
    height:80%; /* IE fix */

    max-width:100%;
    width:auto !important; /* IE fix */
    width:100%; /* IE fix *

}
```

Some Markup:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="featured">
    <div id="featured-images">
      <img src="lib/imgs/fi-1.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, this page works on Chrome. It even works in IE6, and IE8+. I haven't tested it in Firefox or Opera. But IE 7 definitely doesn't play ball. It seems to shrink the image to quite a small degree, as if the browser has been resized to a stump.

I know it's not ideal, but I've been using [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com/index.php) to test.

Comment: your using min-width hack not max width hack

Comment: @Hushme Could you elaborate? Or provide an alternative?

Comment: you are using 100% why you need max width?

Comment: @Hushme Because the images may be larger in size than the containing element. Without a max-width they will overflow the `#featured-images` div.

Comment: Someone must have a non-JavaScript, non-explicit width/height solution to this...

Comment: u should use width:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fixed, you can check it here:

```
<style type="text/css">
#content {
    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:320px;
    max-width:800px;
    width:80%;
    background-color:green;
}
#featured {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#featured-images {
    text-align:center;
}
#featured-images img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
</style>

<div id="content">
    <div id="featured">
        <div id="featured-images">
            <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or here Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fqebe/1/

Cheers!

Comment: And what about the `max-height`? I don't want the image to be more than 80% of the current browser height...

Comment: @shennan: For sure you can change `max-height:100%;` to `max-height:80%;` there is no issue at all.

Comment: Apologies, was being dim. This seems to have done the trick - although it has messed IE6 up. But I'm happier with IE7 working for the moment. I can hack at IE6 separately. Out of interest, why does sticking auto after the `max-width` and `max-height` properties seem to fix things?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer Conditional Comment Style Sheet...

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/ieccss

Works without JavaScript enabled.

No need for hacks, if IE requires the wrong values (e.g. height/width) instead of what you use then only the versions of IE you need to apply those pseudo-right values to will work.

That will let you keep all the IE-related nastiness out of your main style sheet and you can use a specific IECCSS per version of IE.

Comment: I'm aware of conditional CSS, but I'm literally just trying to get this to work. Will implement neat(ish) separation of style-sheets once I know what works and what doesn't.